# C# Index out of bounds

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to make a linear search where the user inputs a selection of numbers and then they input a random number and the program shows if it is in the list or not.

```
    int[] list = new int[10];
        bool found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 12;)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number to be stored.");
            list[i] =Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number you want to find.");
        int n1 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10;)
        {
            if (list[i] == n1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n1 + " is in the list.");
                found = true;
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else i++;

        }
        if (found == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element not in this list.");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

I am pretty sure that the problem lies in this snippet of code.

```
    int[] list = new int[10];
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12;)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number to be stored.");
        list[i] =Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        i++;
    }
```

An array beings with 0 so there are 11 element spaces right?
So when i run it, i go past entering the 10th number and when i enter the 11th, it breaks and says

```
    System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'
```

Comment: No. Please read [Single-Dimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays). You declare the number of elements of the array, not the index of the last element.

Comment: If you use `for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)` then it will automatically use the current length of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I'd recommend you read up on `for` loops and arrays in C#.

Secondly you don't want to *hardcode* the length in the for loop - let the framework do it for you using `list.Length`.  You're seeing the crash because you're trying to assign a value to your array, but the index within your array doesn't exist.

```
int[] list = new int[10];
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
{
   // Do work with list[i]
}
```

Comment: Ah ok. Also, i if i wanted the user to input how many objects to be in the array, i would just ask that question, store it as a variable and then replace the 10 with that number?

Comment: @ExiusCain Yes, you could do that, or it might be more convenient to let the user enter a blank line when they have finished entering the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `int[10];` you tell it to have 10 entries. They are counting from zero, yes, but that just means that your array has the indices `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`.

Your loop goes from `i = 0` up to `i = 11` before it stops because it's no longer smaller than twelve. But the index for the array can at most be `9`.

If you set a breakpoint, you should be able to look at the array contents in a debugger. This way, you could also test such things yourself.

Comment: off topic but what is a breakpoint and why would i use it?

Comment: @ExiusCain Being able to step through a program in a debugger is often immensely helpful. See e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019) for more info, but in short: When you run the program in the debugger, it will be paused at the breakpoints you specify. Then you can inspect which variable has what value at that exact moment. This allows you to see what is actually happening and whether it matches your assumptions

Comment: @ExiusCain No problem! I'm surprised you didn't come accross that yet, but are good enough to be able to track down the problems as far as you did in this question. Good job! I'm happy to help

Answer (score 0):

It should be i < 10 or i <= 9 if your array only holds 10 objects. The 10 indices will be 0-9.